# Android-Compressing and Decompressing Video

Tags: android, video, compression

I am trying to compress a video in Android before uploading. I am following a code from Stack, when I try it I can see that the file is compressed (not sure that it has actually compressed) but it reduces the file size and creates a compressed file as expected but I wont be able to open the file as its content is gibberish so I try to decompress the video as I can surely know that it has been successfully compressed which in turn has lead to decompression.
My problem is that the **original file size** and the **decompressed file size** is **SAME**, but the file does not open and it says "Sorry, the video cannot be played".

**CODE :**

**Compression :**

```
public static void compressData(byte[] data) throws Exception {
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new        
    File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/compressed_video.mp4"));
    Log.e("Original byte length: ", String.valueOf(data.length));
    Deflater d = new Deflater();
    DeflaterOutputStream dout = new DeflaterOutputStream(out, d);
    dout.write(data);
    dout.close();
    Log.i("The Compressed Byte array is ", ""+data.length);
    Log.e("Compressed byte length: ",
            String.valueOf(dout.toString().getBytes().length));


}
```

**Decompression :**

```
            public static void decompress() throws Exception {
           InputStream in = new        FileInputStream("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/compressed_video.mp4");
            InflaterInputStream ini = new InflaterInputStream(in);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
            int b;

            while ((b = ini.read()) != -1) {
                bout.write(b);

            }

            ini.close();
            bout.close();

            String s = new String(bout.toByteArray());
            System.out.println(s);

            File decompressed_file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/decompressed_video.mp4");
            FileOutputStream out_file = new FileOutputStream(decompressed_file);
            out_file.write(bout.toByteArray());
            out_file.close();
            Log.i("The Decompressed Byte array is ", ""+bout.toByteArray().length);

            Log.e("De-compressed byte length: ",
                    String.valueOf(bout.toByteArray().length));
        }
```

From the above code, the original byte length and the decompressed byte length is same but I am not sure why the byte array does not get write to the file. I can see that the two files of compressed_video and decompressed_video is created but I cant play either. Unable to play compressed_video.mp4 is acceptable but I should be able to play the decompressed_video.mp4 which is unavailable to play. I have been sitting on this for more than 2 days so any help would be **insanely appreciated**. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: did you find any solution for this?